# Hibernate not fetching subentity if distinct not present

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have the following domain:
Members and Channels.

Member - equivalent of a user.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

}
```

Channel - Will group blog posts by topic.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "channel")
public class Channel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

The members can be assigned to channels thus becoming members in the channel. So we have the ChannelMember entity since we don't always want to retrieve both ends of the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "channel_member")
public class ChannelMember {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", nullable = false)
    private Channel channel;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id", nullable = false)
    private Member member;
}
```

We use Spring Data JPA and MySQL for our persistance(Spring Boot 1.5.3 Release).

Why is the distinct mandatory in the JPQL query for Hibernate to be able to fetch any records in the following case?

Repository code example as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {
    @Query("select cm.member from ChannelMember cm")
    List<Member> getNotWorking(); // empty List will be returned

    @Query("select distinct cm.member from ChannelMember cm")
    List<Member> getWorking();
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by not working. any exceptions or empty output?

Comment: The result of the query will be an empty List.

Comment: Did you try moving this method in the ChannelMember repository? I think it needs the distinct because the same member can belong to multiple channels so without 'distinct' it would have to include multiple copies of the same Member in the resulting list. Another option: make this method return a Set<Member> and make sure .equals() and hashCode() are properly implemented for Member.

Comment: @MátéLáng any chances for using `p6spy` to see actual SQL ?

Comment: ...or use `hibernate.show_sql=true` (wherever appropriate). The actual SQL could provide clues!

Comment: can you paste the code where you call these repository methods. both the method invocations